# Creating a Date Slider for Vega-Lite Plot in Deneb

Tags: powerbi, visualization, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I'm working with Vega-Lite (Deneb) to create a line plot, and I need to incorporate a date slider to interactively filter the data displayed on the plot. I have the following plot code that visualizes stock data over time. However, I'm unsure how to implement a date slider to allow users to dynamically adjust the date range displayed on the plot. Here's my current plot code:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "title": {"text": {"expr": "data('dataset')[0]['title']"}},
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "Sum of Price", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Price"},
    "color": {
      "field": "Ticker",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "range": {"field": "Colour"}
      }
    },
    "strokeWidth": {"value": 2}
  },
  "config": {
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"}
  }
}
```

An example of my desired output is

[image: Example]

or even something textual like

[image: example 2]

Thanks in advance.

*Edit
My pages each have multiple plots, so while Davids answer is correct, I'm looking for a solution that does not require placing and configuring multiple slicers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a native PowerBI slicer with your date field. This will filter the data that is supplied to Deneb.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For an in chart slicer, a [Scale Domain](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAEyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOOAKwAGM5SgRiikADM225JjShMATxxx912wF9-JWIoOSg1NABtUAB3GmV6NAAWAA4zJWRtAGt9JG04FCU4WVDlGlkyNxAADyr7GjhBZX1VTB8lT299NoQcJyQ9JWgBn00VNmRyqohGuChMdnl0Jm0GCBgQQKUkapoIKoXMQVGQTaCQDzqGpv0cbRoodpBOk4BHBiRZQ7UaUjOg2LxRKoVLpDBwGhkLBoABsYMyOXQeQKdhmx3miyqKzWGzGL305Ta2mIAzsxVK5TI+1QkRqIAAuko5PpIgg2Gs4Mo2DFZAoAARxWRcmKoNkchg4el8gB8AvKwtF7JmbNIAEI7JhtJ8III1CdWUrOdzeXKhdzFeLJTLTQqxcq2Gq7AAvNgTfQxeCNdUZPKI0D1QR6dAAYgAzOG7AHBAB5HBIKB0S6oSwARjEJiGmrYWROHpEmyU+Rkgj+6DIgjYTFJWxA5LYZQqVVqY3qjWa6FaT3x6B6fS1gxAOz2dScLn0AFIAJpnJRJ-3XdsgO4PLteN4fL50H5-ba7anuB5ZADC7K+aFDSjI93b9gGM0CgXp-iAA) can be used. This allows "zooming" in and out of data via a range on the x axis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).